# Usando comando WITH AS em Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Eu vi este exemplo abaixo, gostaria de saber como este comando `With [name] AS` funciona no Sql Server, e quais seus usos em comparação com tabelas em memória ou `SubQueries`, em termos de performance.

```
  With ClientesAtivos AS
    (
            SELECT Id from Client WHERE IsActive = 1
    ),
    ClientesInativos AS
    (
            SELECT Id from Client WHERE IsActive = 0
    )
    SELECT * FROM ClientesAtivos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM ClientesInativos
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A palavra reservada 'WITH' é usada no SQL para criar uma CTE ([Common Table Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx))

**Explicação :**

"Podemos pensar em uma expressão de tabela comum (CTE) como sendo um conjunto de resultados temporário definido no escopo de execução de uma única instrução SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ou CREATE VIEW. Uma CTE é semelhante a uma tabela derivada que não é armazenada como um objeto e permanece apenas durante a duração de uma consulta. Ao contrário de uma tabela derivada, uma CTE pode ser autorreferenciada e pode ser referenciada várias vezes na mesma consulta."

**Utilidade prática**

Geralmente utilizamos as CTE para formar estruturas hierárquicas pois é uma forma muito mais performática e teoricamente mais simples.

Exemplo:

```
-- Cria tabela base
CREATE TABLE Empregado
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    cargo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    id_supervisor INT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT fk_productSales_pid 
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Empregado(id)    
);

-- Popula a tabela (reparem na sintaxe do insert, 
-- só é permitida no SQL Server 2008 ou superior).
INSERT INTO Empregado VALUES 
(1, 'Thiago Zavaschi', 'Diretor', null),
(2, 'Angelina Jolie', 'Gerente de Vendas', 1),
(3, 'Megan Fox', 'Gerente de Marketing', 1),
(4, 'Uma Thurman', 'Vendedor', 2),
(5, 'Jessica Alba', 'Vendedor', 2),
(6, 'Julia Roberts', 'Estagiário', 3);

;WITH hierarquia(id, nome, cargo, id_supervisor, nivel_hierarquia)
AS
(
    SELECT  id, nome, cargo, id_supervisor, 1 as nivel_hierarquia
    FROM Empregado
    WHERE id_supervisor IS NULL 
    -- Perceba que aqui no âncora temos como retorno somente o diretor.
    UNION ALL -- Ligação para a recursão
    SELECT e.id, e.nome, e.cargo, e.id_supervisor, nivel_hierarquia + 1 
    FROM Empregado e
    INNER JOIN hierarquia h ON h.id= e.id_supervisor 
)
SELECT * FROM hierarquia
```

[Link tutorial CTE](http://zavaschi.com/index.php/2009/09/entendendo-as-common-table-expressions-cte-parte-2-final/)

Comment: bom exemplo e explicacao! valeu!

Answer (score 11):

Esta sintax não funcionaria, o correto é:

```
With ClientesAtivos AS
(
        SELECT Id from Client WHERE IsActive = 1
),
ClientesInativos AS -- apenas um WITH, os demais são separados por vírgula)
(
        SELECT Id from Client WHERE IsActive = 0
)
SELECT * FROM ClientesAtivos
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM ClientesInativos
```

A query acima traria exatamente o mesmo resultado de:

```
SELECT id FROM Client WHERE IsActive = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM Client WHERE IsActive = 0
```

Não sei reponder a dúvida sobre performance, eu particularmente só uso o WITH para buscar X resultados de determinado item, ex:

```
-- AS mais tocadas da semana

With MaisTocadas AS
    (
            SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY estilo ORDER BY quantidade DESC) AS validacao from musica
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM musica mu
    INNER JOIN maistocadas mt ON mu.id_musica=mt.id_musica AND mt.validacao <= 10
    WHERE mu.estilo IN ('ROCK', 'POP')
 -- o inner exclui as que não estão entre as 10 mais de cada estilo
    ORDER BY mu.estilo, mt.validacao DESC
```

Isto buscaria as músicas com maior quantidade de cada estilo, apenas um exemplo.

Comment: Certo, eu tinha escrito errado. perfeito!