# Somar cases em uma query

Tags: sql, query, script

Preciso criar uma *query* que some 2 *cases*, porém não estou conseguindo da maneira que fiz.
Caso o campo `D3_UM = 'PC'`, ele deve somar o campo `D3_QTSEGUM`.
Caso o campo `D3_UM <> 'PC'`, ele deve somar o campo `D3_QUANT`.

No fim, ele deve somar os campos `D3_QTSEGUM` e `D3_QUANT` e trazer o resultado.

Trazer a soma de cada um, consegui, porém ele lista 2 registros (um para quando o campo é igual a PC e outro para quando o campo é diferente de PC).
Poderiam me dar uma luz?

Segue *script* desta para citada. É um *subselect*

```
    SELECT...,
    (SELECT CASE 
                WHEN sd3_sub1.D3_UM = 'PC' THEN sum(sd3_sub1.D3_QTSEGUM) 
                WHEN sd3_sub1.D3_UM <> 'PC' THEN sum(sd3_sub1.D3_QUANT)
         END AS D3_QUANT
                FROM SD3010 AS sd3_sub1 WITH(NOLOCK)        
                WHERE sd3_sub1.D3_TM = '010'                
                    AND sd3_sub1.D3_LOCAL IN ('01','02','98')
                    AND sd3_sub1.D3_EMISSAO BETWEEN (LEFT(sd3.D3_EMISSAO,6) + '01')
                                                    AND (LEFT(sd3.D3_EMISSAO,6) + '31')             
                    AND sd3_sub1.D3_FILIAL = sd3.D3_FILIAL
                    AND sd3_sub1.D3_CC LIKE LEFT(sd3.D3_CC,5) + '%'             
                    AND sd3_sub1.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' group by sd3_sub1.D3_UM) AS Producao
FROM ...
```

Com o *WITH* funcionou (segue abaixo), porém, por ser um *subselect* está dando erro na query, quando implemento na query original (que possui os *subselects*, como citado acima).

```
WITH SOMATORIA (SOMA_TOTAL) AS
(SELECT sum(CASE 
            WHEN sd3_sub1.D3_UM = 'PC' THEN sd3_sub1.D3_QTSEGUM 
            WHEN sd3_sub1.D3_UM <> 'PC' THEN sd3_sub1.D3_QUANT
     END) AS D3_QUANT
            FROM SD3010 AS sd3_sub1 WITH(NOLOCK)        
            WHERE sd3_sub1.D3_TM = '010'                
                AND sd3_sub1.D3_LOCAL IN ('01','02','98')
                AND sd3_sub1.D3_EMISSAO BETWEEN ('20170201')
                                                AND ('20170231')                
                --AND sd3_sub1.D3_FILIAL = sd3.D3_FILIAL
                AND sd3_sub1.D3_CC LIKE ('13603%')              
                AND sd3_sub1.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
                group by D3_UM
                )
                SELECT SUM(SOMA_TOTAL) FROM SOMATORIA
```

Comment: Olá Thiago, considere aceitar minha resposta se ela lhe foi útil. Se achar que ela está incompleta ou não te atende, faça os devidos comentários para que eu possa melhorá-la.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `else` em seu `case`:

```
WITH SOMATORIA (SOMA_TOTAL) AS
  (SELECT CASE WHEN 
        sd3_sub1.D3_UM = 'PC' THEN sum(sd3_sub1.D3_QTSEGUM) 
        ELSE sum(sd3_sub1.D3_QUANT)
   END AS D3_QUANT
        FROM SD3010 AS sd3_sub1 WITH(NOLOCK)        
        WHERE sd3_sub1.D3_TM = '010'                
            AND sd3_sub1.D3_LOCAL IN ('01','02','98')
            AND sd3_sub1.D3_EMISSAO BETWEEN (LEFT(sd3.D3_EMISSAO,6) + '01')
                                            AND (LEFT(sd3.D3_EMISSAO,6) + '31')             
            AND sd3_sub1.D3_FILIAL = sd3.D3_FILIAL
            AND sd3_sub1.D3_CC LIKE LEFT(sd3.D3_CC,5) + '%'             
            AND sd3_sub1.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' group by sd3_sub1.D3_UM)
SELECT SUM(SOMA_TOTAL) FROM SOMATORIA
```

Será necessário utilizar o [`WITH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175972.aspx) porque o `SUM` não permitira outra função de agregação ou subconsulta.

Veja mais em [Usando comando WITH AS em Sql Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88676/usando-comando-with-as-em-sql-server).

Comment: Até trouxe os 2 registros também, como comentei na pergunta, porém o problema é a somatória. Teria de somar estes 2 registros e trazer um só (a soma dos 2).

Comment: @ThiagoAlessandro Atualizei a resposta. Não tinha entendido que a somatória deveria ser com as duas colunas já somadas.

Comment: funcionou certinho, porém, esta parte é um subselect e está dando erro quando coloco o with. Tem alguma regra para inclusão dele? Atualizei na pergunta

Comment: Entendi, neste caso, por ser parte de outra consulta, não vai funcionar desta forma. O `WITH` teria que englobar a consulta inteira, ou seja, no último select, o que possui o `SUM(SOMA_TOTAL)` você montaria sua consulta completa, mas, sem a subconsulta da soma.

Comment: Entendi. Com os valores fixos ele funciona perfeitamente. Problema é que ele teria de pegar os valores do Where do select principal (campo sd3.D3_EMISSAO, por exemplo). Aí já complica =\