# Por que é obrigatório o uso do ';' na cláusula WITH?

Tags: sql, sql-server, característica-linguagem, sintaxe

Sempre fiz uso do [`WITH`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) em minhas consultas, no entanto, nunca entendi exatamente o porquê é requerido o '**;**' antes da cláusula `WITH`.

O Erro é bem sucinto, mas dá uma ideia que o `WITH` exige que a instrução anterior seja encerrada, mas por quê?

**Consulta que gera o problema**
*Se alterar para* `;WITH`*, não gera o erro.*

```
DECLARE @pID INT = 1

WITH CTE_TABELA AS
    (SELECT * FROM TABELA) 
SELECT * FROM CTE_TABELA CTE
WHERE CTE.ID = @pID
```

Mensagem de erro no SQL:

> **Msg 319**, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>     Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

*Português*

> Sintaxe incorreta perto da palavra-chave 'WITH'. Se esta declaração for uma expressão de tabela comum, uma cláusula xmlnamespaces ou uma cláusula de contexto de rastreamento de alterações, **a instrução anterior deve ser encerrada com um ponto-e-vírgula**.

A mesma questão se aplica também as cláusulas:
 - [`WITH XMLNAMESPACES`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/xml/add-namespaces-to-queries-with-with-xmlnamespaces)
 - [`WITH CHANGE_TRACKING_CONTEXT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/work-with-change-tracking-sql-server)

**Referências**
[Usando expressões de tabela comuns](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)
[Usando comando WITH AS em Sql Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88676/usando-comando-with-as-em-sql-server)

Comment: O problema é que a palavra `WITH` pode ser utilizada como `hint` também e isso confunde o compilador.

Comment: @Sorack Nossa! Isso faz total sentido! Isso complementa a resposta do Maniero e justifica o que ele disse sobre o compilador. Obrigado!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema não é com o `WITH`, é com a declaração anterior que precisa ser encerrada. O compilador nem sempre consegue identificar corretamente o local e dá uma mensagem enganosa, mas se fizer isto funciona:

```
DECLARE @pID INT = 1;
```

Não importa o que vem depois.

Inclusive pode não ter um `;` antes se a declaração anterior não precisar dele, exemplo:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
WITH DirectReports(Name, Title, EmployeeID, EmployeeLevel, Sort)  
AS (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255), e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName),  
        e.Title,  
        e.EmployeeID,  
        1,  
        CONVERT(varchar(255), e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName)  
    FROM dbo.MyEmployees AS e  
    WHERE e.ManagerID IS NULL  
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255), REPLICATE ('|    ' , EmployeeLevel) +  
        e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName),  
        e.Title,  
        e.EmployeeID,  
        EmployeeLevel + 1,  
        CONVERT (varchar(255), RTRIM(Sort) + '|    ' + FirstName + ' ' +   
                 LastName)  
    FROM dbo.MyEmployees AS e  
    JOIN DirectReports AS d ON e.ManagerID = d.EmployeeID  
    )  
SELECT EmployeeID, Name, Title, EmployeeLevel  
FROM DirectReports   
ORDER BY Sort;  
GO
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/WithSyntax.sql).

Retirado da [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).