# Pegar Lacunas em uma sequencia SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Olá, hoje eu possui um select que me retorna o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Faço outro select que me retorna um valor, 5 por exemplo. Eu precisaria saber quais são os numeros que não estão entre o numero 1 até o numero 5. No meu caso precisaria do seguinte resultado 2, 4, 5.

Precisaria de ajuda para desenvolver essa logica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a cláusula `WITH` para gerar a sequencia de número e compará-la com a tabela em questão:

```
WITH sequencias
  AS (SELECT 1 AS sequencia
      UNION ALL
      SELECT s.sequencia + 1 AS sequencia
        FROM sequencias s
       WHERE s.sequencia <= 5)
SELECT s.*
  FROM sequencias s
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM tabela t
                   WHERE t.nr_volume = s.sequencia)
 ORDER BY s.sequencia
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

---

Temos uma ótima explicação do comando `WITH` na [resposta da pergunta **Usando comando WITH AS em Sql Server**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/92143/59479).