# Encontrar número inexistente tabela

Tags: sql-server

Tenha uma tabela com a seguinte estrutura:

```
------------------------
Codigo | Num_doc | Serie 
------------------------
     1 |    1    |   1
     2 |    1    |   2
     3 |    3    |   2
     4 |    2    |   1
     5 |    3    |   1
     6 |    5    |   1
     7 |    7    |   1
     8 |    5    |   2
------------------------
```

Preciso realizar um select para obter os `Num_doc` que "saltaram" para cada `Serie`, ou seja, a consulta precisa me retornar:

```
---------------
Num_doc | Serie 
---------------
   4    |   1
   6    |   1
   2    |   2
   4    |   2
---------------
```

Comment: pode ser uma procedure? e o número do documento (`Num_doc`) é a base para o cálculo?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Pegar Lacunas em uma sequencia SQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/352364/pegar-lacunas-em-uma-sequencia-sql)

Comment: `select Codigo from tbExemplo where Codigo not in (select Num_doc from tbExemplo)` Seria isso?

Comment: Murilo, o que você quer está claro, pelo menos para mim. O seu tópico foi bloqueado aqui e não há como respondê-lo. Se você quiser, poste sua dúvida no fórum "SQL Server - Desenvolvimento Geral" -> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/pt-BR/home?forum=520

Comment: @JoséDiz apesar de concordar com o fato de que o tópico está claro, como eu citei em um comentário passado, essa pergunta já possui resposta na pergunta [**Pegar Lacunas em uma sequencia SQL**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/352371/59479).

Answer (score 2):

Para encontrar os intervalos há uma série de sugestões na web classificadas como "*gaps and islands*". Eis uma das sugestões, adaptada do artigo "[The SQL of Gaps and Islands in Sequences](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)":

```
-- código #1
with C as (
SELECT Serie, Num_doc, 
       row_number() over (partition by Serie order by Num_doc) as rownum
  from tabela
)
SELECT Cur.Serie as [Série], (Cur.Num_doc + 1) as [Início faixa], (Nxt.Num_doc - 1) as [Final faixa]
  from C as Cur
       inner join C as Nxt on Cur.Serie = Nxt.Serie 
                               and Nxt.rownum = Cur.rownum + 1
  where Nxt.Num_doc - Cur.Num_doc > 1;
```

Substitua *tabela* pelo nome da tabela.

---

Sugiro a leitura do artigo “[Geração de sequências numéricas](https://portosql.wordpress.com/artigos/)” caso necessite de gerar valores sequenciais e sem saltos.